# Is $Z_n$ a Martingale with mean $1$?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, probability-distributions, martingales

Consider a sequence of independent tosses of a coin, and let $P_h$ be the probability of a head on any toss. Let $A$ be the hypothesis that $P_h = a$, and let $B$ be the hypothesis that $P_h = b$. Let $X_i$ be the outcome of the i:th toss, and set $$Z_n = \frac{P\{X1,...,Xn|A\}}{P\{X1,..., Xn|B\}}$$
I was just wondering then if $P_h = b$, is it true that $Z_n,n \geq 1$, is a martingale having mean 1 with respect to $X_n,n \geq 1$?

If it is then can someone show me how?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One form is $Z_n=\prod_{k=1}^n \left[\frac{a}{b}(1-X_k)+\frac{1-a}{1-b}X_k\right]$ where $X_k=0$ for head and $X_k=1$ for tail.

Comment: So I don't get it, is it actually a martingale with mean 1?

Comment: Yes. In this notation, and under the given assumptions, $E(X_n)=1-b$.